# Update top(1) null in column in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I've got a table with the following structure:

```
ULI       DLI       others
itemu1    itemd1    itemo1
itemu2    itemd2    itemo2
itemu3    NULL      itemo3
itemu4    NULL      NULL
```

My goal is to insert a value into the column DLI where the first NULL is. I have tried variations of the following query but they don't work:

```
"UPDATE COUNT(1) table SET 'DLI' = @DLI WHERE 'DLI' IS NULL;"
```

I always get a syntax error with "count" and I'm not sure what the best way is to solve it.

Comment: SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  There is no such thing as a "first" row of any type.  Also, does your table have a primary key?  And what is the `COUNT(1)` supposed to be doing?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have a primary key and that this is what you mean by the ordering that defines "first", you can do:

```
update t
    set dli = 'DLI'
    from (select min(pk) as minpk from t where t.dli is null) tt
    where t.pk = tt.minpk;
```

The `pk` in your case might be `uli`.

I have no idea what the `COUNT(1)` is doing in your query.